# How fast can the ejecta from an asteroid impact go, while remaining solid?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, collision, asteroids

A large asteroid strikes Earth hard enough so that chunks of rock from Earth are ejected back into space.

Roughly how fast could these ejected chunks go, without receiving so much heat energy they melt or vaporize? Or more specifically, is it possible that a chunk could receive a speed sufficient to escape from the Sun's gravity well (42 km/s), without melting or vaporizing?

Comment: Would you accept that a chunk be large enough that even though the frontal part melts and/or vaporised, there is still a bit leftover that escapes?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent yes